# animate на scroll-e

Tags: jquery

вот есть такой js - код , он позволяет зафиксировать в одной позиции мой блок на прокрутке:

.js

```
    var menu = $('#menu');
    var scroll; 
    var trigger =false;
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
             scroll = $(this).scrollTop();  
             if(scroll >=100){
                     menu.css('top', scroll+100+'px');
             } else {
                 menu.css('top',200+'px');
                 trigger =false;
             };
    });

.css

#menu {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

но вот я хочу что бы не css - top было , а была анимация - как тут ( левый блок )

Когда-то задавал такой-же вопрос - но тогда и css хватило - а сейчас анимация нужна

спасибо ( после ответа удалю ссылку )

Comment: А собственно, какую именно вы анимацию хотите? Что и как должно анимироваться? Потому как ваша ссылка "как тут ( левый блок )" - ведёт на какую-то загадочную страницу, где я никак не могу рассмотреть тот самый "левый блок", который хоть как-то бы анимировался. ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сталкивался, все то же самое, css `->` animate и не забываем `stop(true)`, иначе анимация будет выстраиваться в ряд, на прокрутке "туда-сюда" будет заметно.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
  scroll = $(this).scrollTop();  
  if(scroll >=100){
    menu.stop(true).animate('top', scroll+100); // jquery не нужен 'px' :)
  } else {
    menu.stop(true).animate('top', 200);
    trigger = false;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

насколько я понимаю нужно вычислять координаты левого блока, потом при scroll stop делать анимацию с easing в нужные координаты. И да, куча всяких свистелок и перделок на сайте мало того что нагружает сторону клиента, так еще и отвлекает самого клиента.